# How to store three small numbers into one double?

Tags: math, optimization, double

I have `int A, B, C`. And `A` is in range `0-9999`, `B` is `0-99`, `C` is `0-99`.

Because the function must return only one `double`, I think of putting them all into one number. Otherwise I need to call function three times.
But I cannot write an efficient code to do this. This will be called millions times, so it should be quite effective, but no ASM.

I need a function `double pack3int_to_double(int A, int B, int C) {}`

Comment: Call the function three times. Please.

Comment: This is unlikely to save you time. Packing and unpacking is slow.

Answer (score 2):

Couldn't you just store A + 1000B + 100000C?

For example, if you wanted to store A = 1234, B = 6, and C = 89, you'd just store

```
89061234
CCBAAAA
```

You can then extract the numbers by casting the double to an `int` and using standard integer division and modulus tricks to recover the individual values.

Hope this helps!

Comment: That's just what I want to do, but still I am looking for an efficient C code for this. I suppose it should have to do something with multiplying, dividing and rounding. But what is the most efficient code for this?

Comment: What if B = 96 and C = 9? 
It will be:
8961234
CBBAAAA and never work.

Comment: The idea is still sound, just fix the formula.

Comment: @FrancescoDeLisi- My apologies - I misread the OP's question and thought that B was always one digit.  Answer updated!

Comment: @templatetypedef the formula is easy to fix, but the concept is wrong at its starting point. Call three times the same formula is not more expensive than call one time a formula packaging n numbers in one.

Answer (score 2):

If A<10,000 and B & C <100, A can be expressed with 14 bits, and B & C with 8 bits. Thus you need 30 bits in total.
You could therefore pack/unpack the integers by shifting it to the right place:

```
int packed = A + B<<14 + C<<22;  
A = packed & 0x3FFF; B = (packed >> 14) & 0xFF; C = (packed >> 22) & 0xFF;
```

Bit shifting is of course MUCH faster than multiply/divide, and you can cast the int to a double and vice versa.

Comment: +1 for realizing that double is not required to pack, it can be just return type.

Comment: Floating point multiplication is actually crazy fast--like single cycle fast--and you don't need any divides, just multiplication by numbers like 0.00001. On the other hand, moving a number from the floating point registers to the integer registers can be quite costly on some architectures.

Answer (score 1):

This is technically not legal C code, so you would use this at your own risk:

```
typedef union {
    double x;
    struct {
        unsigned a : 14;
        unsigned b : 7;
        unsigned c : 7;
    } y;
} result_t;
```

The C standard doesn't allow using a union member to write a value and a different one to read it out, but I am not aware of a compiler that does the static analysis to diagnose such a problem (it doesn't mean one won't do so in the future).  Also, using certain `int` values may result in a trap representation for a `double`. But, if you know your system will not generate any trap representations, you can consider using this.

```
double pack3int_to_double(int A, int B, int C) {
    result_t r;
    r.y.a = A;
    r.y.b = B;
    r.y.c = C;
    return r.x;
}

void unpack3int_from_double (double X, int *A, int *B, int *C) {
    result_t r = { X };
    *A = r.y.a;
    *B = r.y.b;
    *C = r.y.c;
}
```

Comment: Also writing to one member of an union and then reading another one is undefined behavior afaik isn't it? Now every mainstream compiler will support that behavior, but still something to keep in mind.

Comment: Thank you, this looks interesting, but I fail to understand how to use it!

Answer (score 0):

You can use out parameters in function call and retrieve all 3 int variables.

Answer (score 0):

You could return a NaN double with the data stored in the mantissa. That gives you 53 bits to utilize. Should be plenty.

http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by your answers, this is what I come up so far. This should be quite efficient, and *only 32 bits are used*, so the `exponent` of the `double` is not touched.

```
struct pack_abc {
    unsigned short a;
    unsigned char b, c;
    int safety;
};

double pack3int_to_double(int A, int B, int C) {
    struct pack_abc R = {A, B, C, 0}; // or 0 could be replaced with something smater, like NaN?
    return *(double*)&R;
}

void main() {
    int w = 1234, a = 56, d = 78;
    int W, A, D, i;
    double p = pack3int_to_double(w, a, d);
    // we got the data packed into 'p', now let's unpack it
    struct pack_abc *R = (struct pack_abc*) & p;
    printf("%i %i %i\n", (int)R->a, (int)R->b, (int)R->c);
}
```

Comment: You are putting a 32 bit struct on the stack then reading out 64 bits. This could have ugly consequences.

Comment: thanks for the hint, maybe adding extra int will make it more safe